# How to extend React library namespace with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

One of the libraries I am using is missing some types.

I am trying to extend its namespace and manually add the types but can't figure out how to do it

I have an `index.d.ts` the root of my project

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/index.d.ts" />
export {}; // this file needs to be a module

declare global {
  export interface LatLng {
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
  }
}

declare namespace MapboxGL {
  export class MarkerView {
  }
}
```

and inside my component

```
  <MapboxGL.MarkerView />
```

but I still have the error `Property MarkerView does not exist`

Here is the `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "noEmit": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
     "alwaysStrict": true,
     "noUnusedLocals": true,
     "noUnusedParameters": true,
     "noImplicitReturns": true,
     "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you please show your tsconfig file?

Comment: I add the tsconfig

Comment: Try this to add this `"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types/", "./src/@types"]` inside `compilerOptions `

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the typo in the namespace declaration, instead of:

```
declare namespace MapboxGl {
```

it should say

```
declare namespace MapboxGL { // Notice the uppercase L
```

Comment: AH thanks! good point but the issue remains. I ll edit my question!